# How to create dropdown for shipping method. Magento 1.9.*

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, shipment, multishipping

How to create dropdown for shipping method, i want to create like this:[image]

How to create it without override checkout\onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml , or it's imposible without changes in template?
My Model_Carrier.php :[image]

My shipping method now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simple override shipping method phtml file in your custom module, then modify code to change shipping method from radio button to dropdown select.